# Android AccessibilityService performAction() method not working

Tags: android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

I am developing an accessibility service for Android. The service calls an app, and that app has a RecyclerView. Then I want to click on an element of the RecyclerView with performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK) but it is not working. I know there are a few similar questions but none of them works for me. Also I checked the official documentation for the class of the performAction method https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo

This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(Accessibility event){
    AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();
    if(source != null){
        List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> list = source.findAccessibilityNOdeInfosByText("mystring");

        list.get(0).performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
    }
}
```

This is my configuration xml file:

```
<accessibility-srvice xmlns...
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType = "feedbackGeneric"
    android:AccessibilityFlags = "flagDefault"
    android:canPerformGestures = "true"
    android:canRetrieveWIndowCOntent = "true"
```

I think I misunderstood something, but i don't know what can be. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simple answer is that while finding the node by text is fine, that particular node was not the node with the desired `onClick` event. The solution is to call

```
list.get(0).getParent().performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK)
```

The clarifying discussion is below

---

I think `.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK)` is right, but there might be some other concerns. Sorry for posting as an answer but a comment is too small.

1. Are you sure the `onAccessibilityEvent` is being called? I don't think that is the right event, but I can't be sure. Maybe put a log in there to ensure it's calling the event when you expect it to be called.
2. Also, looking at the source might restrict your search, maybe instead of `event.getSource()` try using `rootInActiveWindow` (I use Kotlin so it might have a method, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService#getRootInActiveWindow(int))

**EDIT: 28 March 2022**

I have run this code on my own accessibility service and it does click the button. But it's very prone to overflow.

```
    var ranOnce = false // prevent overflow
    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
        if (event == null) return

        if (event.eventType == TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED) return

        if (event.source != null && !ranOnce) {
            val nodeList = rootInActiveWindow.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText("Menu")
            //event.source.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText("Menu") // <-- always nothing in list

            Log.d("onAccessibilityEvent", "List of nodes: $nodeList")
            if (nodeList.size > 0) {
                android.util.Log.d("onAccessibilityEvent", "Node info: ${nodeList[0]}")
                ranOnce = true
                nodeList[0].performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK) //<-- caused an infinite loop!
            } else {
                Log.d("onAccessibilityEvent", "No nodes found")
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("onAccessibilityEvent", "event.source is null!")
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1- Yes, the onAccessibilityEvent is being called.

2- I will try with rootInActiveWindow, but what's the difference with getSource(), because one returns the accessibilitynodeinfo of the root node and the other one returns the accessibilitynodeinfo of the event source.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityRecord#getSource() - returns the particular node where that event occurs, whereas rootInActiveWindow is the whole heirarchy - so when you search for the node you can search the whole thing, rather than just the source event - that's what I meant by "restrict(ing) your search"

Comment: If you could post on open repo (even a dummy one or just give more of a code sample) I'm happy to try figure this out with you

Comment: After testing with getRootInActiveWindow() it also does not work :(

Comment: I think you need to check if there are any nodes being returned in the search. ACTION_CLICK definitely works so it might be your search criteria is wrong. I have added code I edited from my own service and I am capable of clicking the node

Comment: Are the elements in your recyclerview loaded and on screen at the time you are calling this?

Comment: Finally i did it. I only had to call to getParent() before performAction() method. Thanks @Quintin Balsdon

Comment: Ah right because it's a RecyclerView and the label is inside a view - nice - glad you found your solution

Comment: I don't understand completely. With list.get(0).performAction() i thought i got the view, but actually with list.get(0).getParent().performAction() i got it. Why it happens that?

Comment: Where is the click listener attached? To the TextView that has the text or to the list item or a container in between?

Comment: It is attached to the itemView object (of the recycler view) which i think is attached to a container

Comment: Yeah so clicking on the TextView itself might not work in the Accessibility Layer. I know that normally when clicked a view will "bubble up" the event, but I am not sure it's the same for a11y services and NodeInfo objects- I think given this problem probably not.

Comment: OK perf. Thx for the help ;)

Comment: @largoWinch is your app works fine in xiaomi devices or other devices ?
is this have android version related blockage ?